# Office Picture Manager not downloading files from Sharepoint Picture Library

Tags: 2010, picture-library

We download images with Office Picture Manager from a picture library in Sharepoint 2010.  It recently stopped working and we began troubleshooting.  We found that if we create another picture library, it works fine.  The problem is with the original library.  Our SP dev believes either the size of the images, or the number of images (over 100,000) might be the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Over 100,000 huh? Are they all in the root folder?

Comment: Not entirely sure.  I know next to nothing about SP, so naturally I have to troubleshoot it.  Do you think we are hitting some kind of hidden limitation?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010377496.aspx

Comment: unless I am missing something, that article doesnt explain my issue.

Comment: Just a jumping off point. There are limitations in lists regarding the number of files in a given view, as well as a maximum number of files that can be queried at once.